# PHP terminal emulator

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, algorithm, terminal

I want to program a "Terminal" emulator in php and jquery or ajax.

My intention it's not to execute real terminal commands, I want to make commands like echo and retrieve me the results to an TextArea, or make commands like newuser and open me a jquery dialog or a webpage. Is there any way to do develop this thing?

The thing i want is a text area where i get the responses and a text input field where i put the commands. The function that needs to do is make a call to a php file where it manages the data input on the text field, compare and do some actions, like a simple echo or a dice rolling. I don't want to manage the system. Thanks to all

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but you have to write some code!

Comment: doesn't matter to write code, what I need is a base to start working

Comment: Maybe you should check out http://uni.xkcd.com/ :)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Fluidbyte/PHP-jQuery-Terminal-Emulator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several **remote (ajax) shells**, which emulate a shell and forward the commands to to the real shell on the server via HTTP(S):

- http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/
- http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Comment: Hi powtac, I don't want a shell that launches commands to the computer, only to emulate this commands getting responses defined by me on a php function, like "roll 2d10" and response: "You've got a 8 rolling 2 dices of 10 faces"

Answer (score 6):

You can check my [jquery terminal emulator plugin](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) it's the best solution if you want to implement custom commands that are implemented by you in PHP. You can also make a real Linux shell with it. But it was created to allow to create of the commands mostly in JavaScript. You can create almost anything you want.

But if you want to have real SSH you probably will not be able to use PHP and you will want xterm.js, but it requires running a server where you keep connection with the server. with jQuery Terminal you can just use PHP.

Comment: The demo shows how to use it with Javascript - but how do you set it up so it would work like a linux shell?

Comment: @cwd Check my leash project which is shell using jQuery terminal http://leash.jcubic.pl/

Comment: And here is simple version of php shell (single file) that works on Windows and Linux server https://github.com/jcubic/jsh.php

Answer (score 3):

Check out the lithium php framework homepage: http://li3.me/

In the top left type help, and see what happens!

Check out the source for informations.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were asking for, but there is a web terminal written in python+JS you may be interested in: http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/

Comment: no mateusaza, im interested on make a self commands to do actions written by me on my webpage such as send a message to someone, retrieve a log file, make a dice rolling, etc