# Emulate command prompt in PHP

Tags: php, c++

I'm writing a little project using PHP, for compiling C++ codes by G++ compiler, How I can simulate or emulate command prompt or anything else inside my webpage for handling "cin" and other functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885014/php-terminal-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the PHP application sits on a web server (not your local computer), you should make sure the compiler exists on the web server.

Assuming the compiler exists, exec() is the function for you.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Additionally, you should take a look at passthru() http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php